# Cannot resolve method 'onCreateOptionsMenu' in 'View'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I'm trying to make a canvas with a menu options to switch between drawing a line and a circle but I'm having trouble displaying the menu

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    final static int LINE = 1, CIRCLE = 2;
    static int curShape = LINE;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyGraphicView(this));
    }
    public class MyGraphicView extends View{
        int startX = -1, startY = -1, stopX = -1, stopY = -1;
        public MyGraphicView(Context context)
        { super(context); }
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
        {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
                    startX = (int) event.getX();
                    startY = (int) event.getY(); break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    stopX = (int) event.getX();
                    stopY = (int) event.getY();
                    this.invalidate();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            switch (curShape) {
                case LINE: canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, paint);
                    break;
                case CIRCLE: int radius = (int) (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(stopX-startX, 2))
                        +Math.sqrt(Math.pow(stopX-startX, 2)));
                    canvas.drawCircle(startX, startY, radius, paint); break;
            }
        }
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
        {
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
            menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Drawing line");
            menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Drawing circle");
            return true;
        }
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case 1: curShape = LINE; return true;
                case 2: curShape = CIRCLE; return true;
            }
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    }
```

So here is the code I've also tried putting the menu code in the main activity class but it doesn't work what should I do. I'm also having the same problem with onOptionsItemSelected

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As seen [here](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/menus#options-menu), the method `onCreateOptionsMenu(...)` should be overriden either...

in an `Activity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

or a `Fragment`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return root;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_menu, menu);
}
```

Comment: If you still want to use the method you created in MyGraphicView,
you can call onCreateOptionsMenu of your custom class from the override method of your Activity class

Comment: @TalhaChaudhry Can you give me an idea of how that would work?

Comment: Sure lemme answer it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking the same code as you provided and updating in way that you can use the menuOptions in your customView class

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    final static int LINE = 1, CIRCLE = 2;
    static int curShape = LINE;
    MyGraphicView myGraphicView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myGraphicView=new MyGraphicView(this)
        setContentView(myGraphicView);
    }
    public class MyGraphicView extends View{
        int startX = -1, startY = -1, stopX = -1, stopY = -1;
        public MyGraphicView(Context context)
        { super(context); }
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
        {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    startX = (int) event.getX();
                    startY = (int) event.getY(); break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    stopX = (int) event.getX();
                    stopY = (int) event.getY();
                    this.invalidate();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            switch (curShape) {
                case LINE: canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, paint);
                    break;
                case CIRCLE: int radius = (int) (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(stopX-startX, 2))
                        +Math.sqrt(Math.pow(stopX-startX, 2)));
                    canvas.drawCircle(startX, startY, radius, paint); break;
            }
        }
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
        {

            menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Drawing line");
            menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Drawing circle");
            return true;
        }
        public Boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case 1: curShape = LINE; return true;
                case 2: curShape = CIRCLE; return true;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        return myGraphicView.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);  // must be the Obj of MyGraphicView
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        Boolean result= myGraphicView.onOptionsItemSelected(item); // must be the Obj of MyGraphicView
        if (result!=null) return result else
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Hope this will clear you the concept